# Magento how to verify order details for a single customer

Tags: php, magento

I have the following code snippet. Does it verify a current customer (by loadByIncrementId) or just last order in the system? How could I rewrite this to verify not by id but customer e-mail? I tried loadBy($customer_email) but it didn't work.

```
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton("checkout/session")->getLastRealOrderId();

    $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
    $amount = $order->getGrandTotal();
    $orderItems = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
    $purchasedSkus = array();
    foreach($orderItems as $orderItem) {
        echo $orderItem->getSku()."|"; 
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to do ?

Comment: I want to list all the SKUs(from getSku()) and GrandTotal (from getGrandTotal()) BASED ON user e-mail (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getEmail();
). OR could you tell me if my code gets the sku for CURRENT USER'S last order or is it the order for the whole system?

Comment: You are getting magento's last order id not the current user.

Comment: how can I rewrite this to get current user's id and data?

Comment: I have given answer to your question. Please try that code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get current customer's data from order. Try using this -

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$email = $customer->getEmail();
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFilter('customer_email', $email)
    ->setOrder('created_at', Varien_Data_Collection_Db::SORT_ORDER_DESC)->setPageSize(1)->getData();

//echo "<pre>";print_r($orderCollection);

$orderId = $orderCollection[0]['increment_id'];
$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
$amount = $order->getGrandTotal();
$orderItems = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
$purchasedSkus = array();
foreach($orderItems as $orderItem) {
    // get sku according to qantity ordered
    $qty = $orderItem->getQtyOrdered();
    for($i=1;$i<=$qty;$i++) {
        $purchasedSkus[] = $orderItem->getSku(); 
    }
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($purchasedSkus);
echo $amount;
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the reply. The code works fine, but when I buy some product with quantity of 3, it only lists one item. How to fix this?

Comment: If you buy an item with quantity 3, it will show one item because you want to get sku of item that will be only one.

Comment: I understand. So what can I do to get SKUs that many times that the quantity of a product? For instance, I ordered product with sku #AA1, with quantity of 3, so how to list this like: #AA1, #AA1, #AA1?

Comment: I have updated my answer, please try that. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$customer_email = "customer@domain.com";
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
   ->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', $customer_email)
   ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');
$last_order = $orders->getFirstItem();

$skus = array();
foreach($last_order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){
   $skus[] = $item->getSku();
}
$grandTotal = $last_order->getGrandTotal();
var_dump($grandTotal);
var_dump($skus);
```